# Vim: How to delete a vim buffer when you quit a file in vim

Tags: vim

I open 15 files in vim.

```
vim -p *.php
```

I close one file without saving

```
:q
```

Then after closing some I get this `E173: 15 more files to edit`.

It seems quitting a file does not remove it from a buffer.

Is there any way so that I don't get this error when I quit a file?

At the moment I have to use `qall` to exit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't `quit` files; in order to "close" a file, you either `delete` or `wipe` the buffer, whereas you `quit` the editor itself. You're using the quit-editor command (`q`) to close a single buffer, which is why you're getting the error message.

Here are the commands you need to know:

- `:bd` closes a single buffer; that is, Vim removes it from the buffer list. Some bits of information, such as marks, are still kept around.
- `:bw` closes a single buffer and `wipe`s it; the buffer is "really" deleted and all temporary information is lost.
- `:q` quits the editor; assumes that only one buffer is open.
- `:qa` (which is short for the `:qall` command you've been using) quits the editor and close **all** buffers. This is separate from `q` because otherwise you might forget that you have other files open and accidentally lose information.

Comment: :q closes a split, it closes the editor only if there is only one window and one split at the moment, so you are wrong.

Comment: @Pencilcheck You couldn't think of a less confrontational way to phrase that? I any case, yes, :q (or :quit) will only close a single window at a time, but it's still the "quit" command and is in fact used to quit the editor.

Comment: @Pencilcheck Contribute by editing the answer. It's a better form of criticizing.

Comment: @sargas ...as long as the edit isn't incorrect....

Comment: @Kyle precisely