# Vim opens symlink even when given target path directly

Tags: linux, vim, symbolic-link

If I open a file through a symlink first, then `:bd` that one and later try to open the actual target of the symlink directly, Vim instead opens the symlink. How do I change this behaviour?

The difference matters in my case for two reasons: (1) `autochdir` goes to the symlink's directory rather than the actual file's directory, and (2) vim-fugitive enables itself only within a git repo, and the target is in a repository while the symlink is not.

Is there some kind of caching going on, and if so how do I disable it for cases like this?

Comment: I also find this annoying (especially when the symlink is outside of a git repository, because in that case `Gstatus` and friends don't work), and the `bufwipe` solution proposed didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, [apparently](https://superuser.com/a/713841/3200) some temporary information is stored about the file even when you do a `:bd`, and to "really" remove a file from Vim's memory, you have to do a `:bw` (bufferwipe). The temporary information about the symlink making the target open as the symlink seems like a bug in Vim, but in any case opening the original symlink again and using `:bw` on it seems to clear up this issue.

Comment: The reason for opening the symlink is that vim is reusing the same inode, making it simple for other programs to detect changes in the file (really different from renaming a new version). Other editors do this; it is not a "bug in Vim".

Comment: @ThomasDickey What "other programs" do you mean in this context? Could you give an example?

Comment: A program such as a pager (or another editor) can have an open file-descriptor on the file, allowing it to read/write parts as needed, and use `fstat` to check if other program(s) have modified it in any way (requiring reload).  If the file is replaced (not using the same inode) it is not possible for others to keep an open file-descriptor on the "same" file.

Comment: Revisiting an old question, but @ThomasDickey I'm not sure if I'm missing something or you are. I don't understand the "If the file is replaced (not using the same inode)" part of your comment - I'm not talking about Vim replacing a file on the disk at all, my question and answer were about Vim's internal metadata about the file. Specifically, what Vim internally sees the file's path `%:p` as while the file is open. I don't think that affects other programs.

Comment: This definitively causes bugs. Like when I want to open a "real file" with fugitive from a git repository and vim insists this file is the symlinked version. Very troublesome to come here to figure out I need to do :bw before I can reopen with another path, and manual says for :bw : Don't use this unless you know what you are doing. (I don't).